# LAG() Function Error Within BigQuery SQL; Unable to return lagged hits.page.pagePath

Tags: google-bigquery

I am currently trying to create a column within a BigQuery table that simply includes the lagged values of the hits.page.pagePath. For this example, imagine that I have hits.time values of 0, 513, 518, 762, 991. These values correspond to a unique_visit_id which I created. There are thousands of unique visits per day, each with different hits.time values and row numbers.

To help with a variety of calculations, I want to add a column to the data frame that simply includes the lagged value for all rows in the hits.page.pagePath column (with there being no lag associated when hits.time > 0). Note that the hits.time is a repeated group that refers to a unique visit id which is calculated using `CONCAT(fullVisitorId, STRING(visitId)) AS unique_visit_id`. Thus, I suspect that a command like OVER would be involved. My initial query used the following approach:

```
SELECT date, LAG(hits.page.pagePath,1), CONCAT(fullVisitorId, STRING(visitId)) AS unique_visit_id, visitId, visitNumber, fullVisitorId, totals.pageviews, totals.bounces, 
hits.page.pagePath, device.deviceCategory, device.browser, device.browserVersion, hits.customVariables.index,
hits.customVariables.customVarName, hits.customVariables.customVarValue, hits.time
FROM (FLATTEN([XXXXXXXX.ga_sessions_20140711], hits.time))
WHERE hits.customVariables.index = 4
ORDER BY unique_visit_id DESC, hits.time ASC
LIMIT 1000;
```

Thus unfortunately returned the error:

**Error: LAG is an analytic function and must be accompanied by an OVER clause.**

**Job ID: XXXXXXXX-XXX:job_zduhuRKgvrgmA7niBzcyb3empwY**

I have guessed that OVER would reference the `CONCAT(fullVisitorId, STRING(visitId)) AS unique_visit_id` since each row containing the same unique_visit_id represents a hit inside a unique visit. Unfortunately, using an OVER here has also returned an error.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Analytic functions have an odd syntax... you're almost there, but you just need to move the `ORDER BY` clause into the `OVER` statement used by `LAG()`:

```
SELECT date, LAG(hits.page.pagePath,1) 
  OVER(PARTITION BY unique_visit_id ORDER BY hits.time ASC) as lagged, 
  CONCAT(fullVisitorId, STRING(visitId)) AS unique_visit_id, visitId, 
  ...
FROM (FLATTEN([XXXXXXXX.ga_sessions_20140711], hits.time))
WHERE hits.customVariables.index = 4
LIMIT 1000;
```

Comment: Thanks. This is excellent. As a follow up, I note that you removed the ORDER BY at the end of the script and left it in the OVER function. Will this guarantee that, when the hits.time = 0 (which is the landing page), the value in lagged will always be 'null'? I want to make sure that later in the table it doesn't accidentally look back onto a different unique_visit_id (which I don't believe it will based on the way the function is written.

Comment: Ahh... I think you want something slightly different then. You want to partition by unique_visit-id and order by hits.time. I've updated the response above.

Comment: I have also a follow up question ... Let me know if you want me to ask it on a different thread. Let's say that I now want to scan through each of the unique_visit_id's and if a URL is found INSIDE just one row within partitions, to create a new column that, for every value of the unique_visit_id, gives a certain output. I was going to use the CASE statement to do it, but am curious if you might have recommendations.

Comment: That might be better to be a separate question, since I'm not completely sure I understand what you're asking. It sounds a bit like you might want to filter on unique ids that have the URL and then OUTER JOIN against it.

Comment: Great. Separate question coming.

Comment: Hi Jordan. I just posted the separate question here. I also included some visual mocked up screen shots to illustrate what I was trying to accomplish without using a JOIN (unless you recommend that a JOIN is the best way to go about it). http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24747744/using-a-case-statement-to-change-the-value-of-a-new-bigquery-column-based-findin